# How Can I generate a requirements file from Pipfile with indexes, without locking?

Tags: python, pipenv, pipfile

I want to generate a requirements.txt file from a Pipfile.

I've tried several tools that do this (pigar, pipenv-to-requirements, pipfile-requirements) but none of them address indexes

Meaning that for the following Pipfile:

```
[[source]] 
url = <some-url>
verify_ssl = true
name = <some-name>
[packages]
statsd = "*"
pytest = "*"
```

I get the following requirements file:

```
pytest
statsd
```

Instead of the expected requirements file with an index:

```
-i <some-url>
pytest
statsd
```

Another solution that was suggested to me is using "pipenv lock":

```
pipenv lock --requirements > requirements.txt
```

But this updates Pipfile.lock - which I **really** want to avoid

Isn't there some way to generate requirements **without** locking?

Answer (score 1):

`pipenv lock --requirements > requirements.txt` isn't working.

```
Error: No such option: -r
```

pipenv version:

```
bash-4.2# pipenv --version
pipenv, version 2022.9.4
```

Following workaround worked:

```
pipenv run pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

With `pipenv version 2023.7.23`

Use the `requirements` command.

`pipenv requirements > requirements.txt`

Also `pipenv requirements --help` for command options.

Comment: I downvoted this by mistake and for some reason can't undo. Sorry for that.